# order by on mysql by count of one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
tid item
1   k1
1   k1
1   k1
1   k2
1   k2
2   k1
2   k3
3   k2
3   k1
3   k4
```

I want to order it from total item, so k1 appear 5 time,, than k2 appear 3 times, k3 and k4 once. I want to order it by tid asc, and count of item desc.

I tried this query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tes2` 
order by count(id_item) desc
```

But it just returns 1 row.

```
tid item
1   k1
```

How to get all of the data?

an output that i want is like this

```
 tid item
    1   k1
    1   k1
    1   k1
    1   k2
    1   k2
    2   k1
    2   k3
    3   k1
    3   k2
    3   k4
```

so its ordered by the count of item.

Comment: Please provide in your question a table with desired output.

Comment: @trincot i already add it, thx man..

Comment: There are five 1's, two 2's and three 3's. And you want the 2's before the 3's?

Comment: It would be better to have example data where the order of the second column is not the same as just ordering it alphabetically.

Comment: @jarlh yup, i want order it by how many item was appear. no ordering alphabetically

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course.

Comment: @strawberry ya i didnt give this table a primary key, because this is just an temp table in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a subquery to get the count for each item and then join that to the main table on item so you can order by count. **Below is MSSQL but you should be able to use this solution in your MySQL query.**

Set up the test --

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
( 
    tid int,
    tem VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (1, 'k1');
INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (1, 'k1');
INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (1, 'k1');
INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (1, 'k2');
INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (1, 'k2');
INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (2, 'k1')
INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (2, 'k3');
INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (3, 'k2');
INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (3, 'k1');
INSERT into @Test (tid, item)   VALUES (3, 'k4');
```

Query --

```
SELECT  t.tid,t.item
FROM    @Test t
JOIN    (SELECT t2.Item, COUNT(*) AS ItemCount FROM @Test t2 GROUP BY t2.Item) counts ON counts.Item = t.Item
ORDER BY counts.ItemCount DESC, t.tid ASC
```

OUTPUT --

```
 tid    item
    1   k1
    1   k1
    1   k1
    2   k1
    3   k1
    1   k2
    1   k2
    3   k2
    2   k3
    3   k4
```

Comment: can i make an output that i want, without create an temporary table?

Comment: of course, the temp table is just there for the example. Use the query I posted and swap out @Test with your table.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT count(id_item), field1, field2, field3
FROM `tes2` 
order by 0 desc
```